# How to deploy sql changes with .NET + Oracle

Tags: .net, oracle, deployment, teamcity

my setup is .NET on the server and Oracle as database. I'm looking for a convenient way to deploy SQL changes continuously.

So far I have a build server (Teamcity) which pulls the changes from DVCS and creates a deploy package. Then I import the package into the IIS.

This works fine, except there isn't happening any SQL deployment. I don't know how to integate the SQL part into this process.

The SQL changes are stored in files and named by date and time and commited into the DVCS.

My requirements are to be able to deploy to different version of the system, that only the needed SQL scripts would be run. Is this even possible ?

I would like to omit any paid third-party tools.

EDIT - there won't be any need to create a new database in this process, it will already exist

Comment: Hello. Can you be more specific please? What is your problem? Continuous Integration for SQL or what?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you consider a 3rd party tool, you may take a look at [FluentMigrator library](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/wiki). You can reference it from your own application, so that it doesn't look like a 3rd party tool.

If you cannot use 3rd party libraries, then you have to do it yourself:

- Maintain a table in your database, that will contain a list of all incremental scripts that were executed on that specific database. Or alternatively, just store the last script that was executed, or a "DB Version number".
- Use naming or numbering convention with your scripts, so that you can determine which scripts were applied and which were not, and apply the scripts in the correct order.
- Write a database migration tool, which will compare the list of the scripts included with the deployment against the "version" table in the target database, determine which of the deployed scripts should be executed, executes them, and then updates the "version" table accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The way i did this, while not ideal has been working for years, I keep the sql scripts sourced in a directory structure that gets zipped up and deployed with my artifacts along with install program I wrote which extracts and iterates over the directories and runs the scripts in a dependency order based on the folder:

- tables
- views
- procs
- triggers
- updates

I run all the scripts with each deploy. In each sql script i handle what to do in an update,

for tables and indexes if exists, skip, else create
stored procedures, views, triggers, drop and recreate (and reassign permissions)
and then an update script to do things like add columns, rename things etc.

This is definitely the hardest thing I've had to manage in our continuous deployment environment. i hope this helps.